# Proof: $ A - (B - C) \subseteq (A - B) - C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Question:**
Prove or disprove the following statements:

For all sets $A, B, C$:

> a) $A - (B - C) \subseteq (A - B) - C$
>
> b) $(A - B) - C \subseteq A - (B - C)$
>
> c) If $A - (B - C) \subseteq (A - B) - C$, then $A \cap C= \varnothing$

**My attempt to answer:**

a) This is false.

b) This is true.

c) This is true.

Are these answers I correct?

Proof: Working on it.

Comment: You have a contradiction in your answers. If __part b__ is __always__ true, then __part c__ is __false__ because you don't have to have $A \cap C = \emptyset$. So, they cannot be both true at the same time.

Comment: sorry @ThePortakal - fixed the question.

Comment: Also, if something is false, you can give a counter-example for a proof. For example to prove that "every person has red hair" is false, you can say "hey look, Angelina Jolie has black hair"

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

For a), consider the case when $B=C$.

> If $B=C$, then $A-(B-C)=A-\varnothing=A$ and $(A-B)-C=A-B$.

b) is true, apologies for my mistake.

For c), note that $A-(B-C)=(A-B) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$

Comment: I am sorry, needed to fixed the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Samim My hint was actually for the corrected version haha

Comment: Not sure what happens when B = C? The statement a) is true and B = C is not a counter example to it. Am I missing something?

Comment: If we let B = C, It becomes $\varnothing \subseteq \varnothing$

Comment: @Samim Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

$(A \setminus B) \setminus C$ is all the elements of $A$ that are not in either B or C (removed one after the other). Intuitively, you would expect it to contain fewer elements that the set that contains all the elements of $A$ save for just the ones that are in $B$ but not $C$.

To see this rigorously: 
$A \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \cap (B \setminus C)^ c = A \cap (B \cap C^c)^c = A \cap (B^c \cup C) = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap C) = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap C) \supseteq (A \setminus B) \supseteq (A \setminus B) \setminus C$.

Naturally, for equality to hold, you need the second term in the set union to be empty, i.e. $A \cap C = \emptyset$. This ensures the second set inequality becomes an equality too.